# Query mongo db for total user count in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node app where I can accept users and display their profile and stuff like that. I want to display a number of all the users in a database on the index page if the current user is logged in. I have the following route in my route.js file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.user) {
        db.users.count(function(err, count){
            res.render('index', {
                count: count,
                user: req.user
            })
        })
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }
});
```

The page displays fine when a user is not logged in but when a user is logged in a the query is called their is a `Cannot read property 'count' of undefined` error displayed.

Comment: What exactly the line which causes an error?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that there is a problem with `db.users`. Are you sure you have a connection to mongo and `db.users` exists?

Comment: The db is connected and I have the user model loaded as  `var User = require('../models/user');`. I know a collection `db.user` exists on the db because I checked it in the shell.